# Highcharts overwrite default DataLabel

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use the following code to overwrite the default `dataLabels` rules when the chart is a pie but it's not working.

What I'm missing ?

```
plotOptions: {
    series:{
        dataLabels:{
            shadow : false,
            allowOverlap:true,
            useHTML: true,
            style :{
                textShadow :'none',
                fontSize:"16px"
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return '<p>'+(this.y).format() + ' ' + suffixe+'</p>';
            }
        }
    },
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style:{
                fontSize:"18px"
            },
            formatter: function() {
                return '<strong>'+ this.point.name +'</strong>: '+ this.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I miss something

Comment: Hi, I think that instead of using plotOptions.series and plotOptions.pie objects, you can change your dataLabels inside more specific series types. For example if your chart have line and pie series, you can use plotOptions.line and plotOptions.pie objects: http://jsfiddle.net/w0cujkbm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code like this to check the type before formatting the `dataLabel` I lose the `fontSize` option but that's ok:

```
plotOptions: {
    series:{
        dataLabels:{
            shadow : false,
            allowOverlap:true,
            useHTML: true,
            style :{
                textShadow :'none',
                fontSize:label_y_size+"px"
            },
            formatter: function () {
                if ( this.series.type == "pie") {
                    return '<strong>'+ this.point.name +'</strong>: '+ (this.y).format();
                } else {
                    return '<p>'+(this.y).format() + ' ' + suffixe+'</p>';
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :**
This bug in highcharts : [link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3881)

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see here is that you're trying to do two things at one. You should be setting your `dataLabels` in either `plotOptions.pie` or `plotOptions.series`, but not both.

Also, you're missing a step for `plotOptions.series`. The proper order is `plotOptions --> series --> point --> dataLabels`.

```
plotOptions: {
    series:{
        point: {    // <-- here is your missing step
            dataLabels:{
                shadow : false,
                allowOverlap:true,
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    textShadow :'none',
                    fontSize:"16px"
                },
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<p>'+(this.y).format() + ' ' + suffixe+'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ... other options
}, // end plotOptions
```

Does this help with your question?

Comment: Following the api, it's plotOptions.series.dataLabels http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels

Comment: You're correct, and thank you for noting that. This method will help you better grab values such as `point.y` to use in formatting the data labels.